# How to use Jinja2 statements to manifest input elements containing certain child elements?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm building my first Flask app (chat app) and trying to interact with the database. Here is part of the code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class ChatBox(FlaskForm):
    message = StringField('', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=10000)])
    send = SubmitField('')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def chat():
    form = ChatBox()
    return render_template('chat.html')
```

Here's the static version of the concerned part of chat.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/" class="empty">
    <input type="text" class="chatbox">
    <button type="submit">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='send.png') }}" class="send">
    </button>
</form>
```

Writing this in Jinja2 is the problem.
For the chatbox I can easily write `{{ form.message(class="chatbox") }}` but how to turn the image into a submit?

I've tried making an `<input type="submit">` element with a *background-image* property but then there is "Submit" text that doesn't go away.

I've also considered using an `<input type="image">` but that won't have the proper "submit" functionalities for the task.

Finally, I put the image into a `<button type="submit">` but now I'm not sure how to manifest this using Jinja2.

Is there a way to mention any child element when displaying a form field using Jinja2? Similar to how you can mention classes? If not, is there a way around any of the other options I mentioned? Or any alternative solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behaviour. Having an empty string as a label and calling `{{ form.send() }}` in the template results in an empty button. I'm using Flask-WTF version 1.0.1 with Jinja2 version 3.1.2. Then you should be able to use `background-image`.

Comment: I did have an empty string in the label and the 'submit' text still won't go away. See: `send = SubmitField('')` in the class definition of ChatBox.

Comment: I've copy and pasted the exact python code from your question, and I am getting a blank submit button. The only thing I changed is adding `form=form` to `render_template` and the `{{ form.send() }}` to the template.
Maybe your browser does some odd cashing or you didn't restart your server?

Comment: @VANN Universal Yeah, you were right. I tried it again and it worked, and using your background-image solution I got what I needed.